# Main menu in Mobile Style on Desktop size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm developing a website and I have some problem with bootstrap/CSS.

http://50.87.248.234/~placehx2/

On this page the main menu changes its style under 992px, but I want it in mobile style even on big size screen.
How have I to modify the media queries?

Many Thanks

Comment: Insert your code here please.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width:1024px) {
  mobile code here
}
```

You can change the width to what you need for the site

Answer (score 0):

This may be a very hacky way of achieving what you would like but if you can't find another way to do it, you could replace all the media min-widths with larger widths.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  //bootstrap classes go here
}
```

This should make the mobile style apply with bigger windows, but it's a bit of a pain to deal with if you plan on updating your bootstrap version later because you'll have to repeat it.  But for a quick fix this will do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which should be a longer but stable solution?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have a solution to that but I'll try think of something.